# I want to resize image by scrolling; however, my function seems wrong. I can't use if condition properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, web

I want to resize an image by scrolling. However, the problem seems to be in my function. I cannot use the if condition properly.

I want the result to be like the Apple website: https://www.apple.com/iphone-11/

```
jQuery(window).scroll(function () {
    var imageWidth = jQuery("img#big").width();
    var stopImage = jQuery("img#big").width(800);

    if (imageWidth >= stopImage) {
        var s = imageWidth - Math.min(imageWidth, $(document).scrollTop() * 20);
        jQuery("img#big").width(s);
    }
});
```

Comment: "var stopImage = 800;"

Comment: @PrikeshSavla Yes!! I tried it, but it doesn't stop at 800, it goes smaller and disappear

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. If you want to ensure a minimum width of 800 Pixels, you will need to test the Width value not set it to 800.

Comment: Make sure you use ``` when formatting your code in your question. Use single ` for one line of code and ``` for multiple lines of code by surrounding it with ```.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i tried to replicate the issue. It seems the multiplier you are using is a bigger value than you'd need.

> scrollTop() * 0.5 or scrollTop() * 2

```js
jQuery(window).scroll(function () {
                                var imageWidth = jQuery("img#big").width();
                                var stopImage =800;

                            if (imageWidth >= stopImage) {
                                var s = imageWidth - Math.min(imageWidth, $(document).scrollTop() * 0.5);

                                jQuery("img#big").width(s);
                            }

                        });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<img id="big" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1660995/pexels-photo-1660995.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=orange-lighthouse-1660995.jpg&fm=jpg">
```

Comment: Happy to help!!

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following code.

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  var position = $(window).scrollTop();
  $(window).on("scroll mousewheel", function(e) {
    var dir = false;
    if (e.type == "mousewheel") {
      dir = e.originalEvent.wheelDelta >= 0;
      // True = Up; False = Down
    } else {
      var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
      dir = !(scroll > position);
      // True = Up; False = Down
    }
    var imageWidth = $("img#big").width();
    var stopImage = 800;

    console.log(e.type, dir, imageWidth, stopImage);

    if (imageWidth >= stopImage && !dir) {
      var s = imageWidth - Math.min(imageWidth, $(document).scrollTop() * 20);
      $("img#big").width(s);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<img id="big" style="width: 1600px; min-width: 800px;" src="https://i.imgur.com/4ILisqH.jpg" />
```

You may want to know the direction that the User is scrolling. In case you want to increase the size.

You can limit the shrinking by a `if()` statement or by CSS with `min-width`.

Comment: cool!!previously I added that min-width and thought it was useless.